# Laptop wont boot & screen flashes on boot Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: screen, radeon, vaio, sony

I own a Sony Vaio E Series laptop that has the screen flashing on boot into Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. Half the time it wont actually boot into Ubuntu, and hangs with a black screen before the login screen appears.Any help Appreciated. Thanks.

Some computer details:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [104d:9096]
    Kernel driver in use: i915


01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [1002:6840]
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [104d:9096]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```